# Is it necessary to replace the determiner "this" with the article "the" when I reduce relative clauses?

Tags: relative-clauses, reduced-relative-clauses

I don't know why the e-book I'm using to learn blames my answer when I'm asked to reduce this sentence:

> *Cars that are parked in this street* will be towed away.

My answer:

> *Cars parked in this street* will be towed away.

The e-book marked my answer incorrect. The key answer from the book is:

> *Cars parked in **the** street* will be towed away.

What is the reason behind the change happened? The title of the e-book is Oxford Grammar by M. Swan, by the way.

Comment: "Cars parked in the street in Oxford will be towed away" means they will be towed away from every street in Oxford, not just the one under discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the "correct" answer in the book is a more natural expression, it has a subtly different meaning, since the "close to the speaker" sense of "this" has been lost.

Probably the person typing the answer key changed "this" to "the" (as for a native speaker "the" is more common) by accident.